# Sqlite exception when there is more data in textfield

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, sql-update, text-database

I am making a sqlite database table as and trying to update my database on click event

```
SQLiteDatabase sd= openOrCreateDatabase("mynotedb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
String sql  ="create table if not exists notecont(title nvarchar(70), description text)";
sd.execSQL(sql);
sd.close();
```

and i am running the following update command which shows me a sqlite exception

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("mynotedb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 String sql="";
 sql = "update notecont set title='"+et2.getText().toString()+"', " +"description='"+et1.getText().toString()+"' where title='"+et2.getText().toString()+"'";
 db.execSQL(sql);
 db.close();
```

The stacktrace for the following is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: update notecont set title='tcs', description='1. what are the it services demand in fiscal 2014 ?

2. how much demand is coming for new services that account technology trends such as social media, mobility and big data ? and what is TCS doing in this regard ?

3. what's the progress TCS has made in cloud computing as TCS is having the biggest success in 2010 i.e from unisys corp.

4. what challenges TCS is facing in Indian it market ? 
' where title='tcs'
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
at bitcream.my.notepad.Newnote.update(Newnote.java:211)
at bitcream.my.notepad.Newnote.checkempty(Newnote.java:386)
at bitcream.my.notepad.Newnote.access$0(Newnote.java:370)
at bitcream.my.notepad.Newnote$2.onClick(Newnote.java:103)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Kindly suggest me a fix. When i add too much text and execute update query it fires me a sqlite error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is probabaly your apostophi at line 3 of your description thats breaking it. ie Whats's

Answer (score 1):

To update a row in your table use [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html)

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", et2.getText().toString());
    values.put("description", et1.getText().toString());

    db.update("notecont", values, "title = ?", new String[] { et2.getText().toString() });
```